# Is it possible in MATLAB to keep a variable in memory without using global variables?

Tags: matlab, global-variables, shared-memory

I have a function that creates/loads a variable. This variable has to be later used in another (separated) function. However, in order to fulfill the software requirements, I cannot pass this variable as an input.
In order to solve this problem, I was thinking to use `global`  variables. However, I'd like to avoid them for several reasons, especially because the runtime increases significantly.
Thus I am seeking a way to do the following tasks

```
function func1(x) 
    global y 
    y = some_long_computation(x);
end
```

and

```
function w = func2(z)
    global y
    w = some_other_stuff(y, z);
end
```

without using global variables.
Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Why is there a "software requirement" to not pass the variable around? I think you've answered your own question if that's impossible... `persistent` variables would be the only alternative, but not across different functions.

Comment: Can the functions be methods to a class? You’d have to call them as `obj.func1(x)` instead of `func1(x)`.

Comment: I think they can. But I never worked with classes before.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is using [`nested functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html):

```
function main
    y = [];
    func1(3);
    w = func2(5);
    
    function func1(x)        
        y = some_long_computation(x);
    end

    function w = func2(z)
        w = some_other_stuff(y, z);
    end
end
```